# How to make a function to read values from the lua file

Tags: lua

Well I'm learning lua and I got a question, I'm trying to create a reading function bool in lua.

I have a function that disables or enables as I score true or false.

This function is called just `useappenabled` that I am not able to apply it on the Moon, before I used in the form of libconfig and functioned normally before was written as follows.

The file is as follows:

```
Enableapp = 
{
    Useapp = true;
};
```

Now reading before shaped libconfig was the following, note that the useappenabled function is applied to the input value, i.e. true or false if I put on the Useapp.

```
if (config_lookup(&onf, "Enableapp"))
        if (config_setting_lookup_bool(cf, "Useapp", &SelectValue))
            useappenabled = SelectValue;
```

So I tried changing the code libconfig to lua, however I am not able to read the `useappenabled` function, the code is as follows in the lua.

```
lua_getglobal(L, "Enableapp");
    lua_pushstring(L, "Useapp");
    lua_tonumber(L, useappenabled);
```

I believe the problem is lua_tonumber, I need to do something more or less like this:

```
useappenabled = value_the_Useapp;
```

But I'm starting lua now, can anybody tell me how can I apply the function `useappenabled` to equal the `Useapp` value.

Answer (score 1):

> not able to apply it on the Moon

That's an issue with most Earthly software. The usual difficulty is *reaching* the Moon.

> I need to do something more or less like this:
>
> ```
> useappenabled = value_the_Useapp;
> ```

```C
lua_getglobal(L, "Enableapp"); // push the table onto the stack
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Useapp"); // index table with "Useapp" and push result onto the stack
useappenabled = lua_toboolean(L, -1); // get the value off the top of the stack into your C code
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mud, worked perfectly, actually I didn't know that could be done that way. A question is there any material that I can look at how to apply lua in C ?

Comment: Another question how can I count the number of existing lua_getglobal in the code for example.

`printf ("there's 32 configuration. \n");`